# Output Class gives me [object Object]

Tags: jquery, string, object

Im trying to get an element class and work with it either as string or plain text:

```
<ul>
    <li class="list1"> list 1 </li>
    <li> list 1.1 </li>
    <li class="list"> list 2 </li>
    <li> list 3 </li>
</ul>
```

Jquery

```
_class = $('.list').closest('*[class]');
alert(_class);
```

This alerts  [object Object] Why does it not alert `list1`?

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/59aD6/)

Comment: Because `_class` is an object?

Comment: It is list1 -- it's just the jQuery wrapper for it. Put `console.log(_class);` instead.

Comment: Care to explain the downvotes

Comment: If you use the debugger you can investigate what is actually in `_class`

Comment: Because `alert()` is not a debugging tool

Comment: 1. `list1` is not a parent of `list` 2. Learn to use `console.log()` 3. `_class`  is an object thus alerts [object Object]

Comment: What part of `_class` are you trying to display? The text contents, the class attribute? `_class` won't contain any elements because there are no ancestors of `.list` that have a `class` attribute (unless there's more in your HTML than you showed).

Comment: @Barmar I would like to do stuff with _class. So far it seems all I can do is output in console

Comment: What stuff? Can you be precise.

Comment: @Youss It seems like you don't understand that jQuery selectors return collections of elements, not attributes. You have to use additional methods to get attributes. You need to read a jQuery tutorial to learn the basics, posting questions like this is not a good way to learn.

Comment: @Barmar Matteo Tassinari has answered what I was looking for

Comment: Look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/ApnLw/1/ It alerts `list`, not `list1` as you requested.

Comment: @Barmar I was looking for a way to 'alter/fashion' the object in my own way. Using [0].className; allows me to do stuff like: _class.split or _class.replace etc. That was actually what I was looking for as stated in question: "and work with it either as string or plain text" The rest is just example code

Comment: OK. The question is confusing because you expected it to alert `list1`, not `list`. So it wasn't clear that you just wanted to get the class name, it also seemed like you wanted to get a different element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is:

```
alert(_class.text());
```

or

```
alert(_class.html());
```

in fact `_class` itself is a jQuery object, hence its string form is `[object Object]`

**EDIT**

If instead you want to inspect the object, use

```
console.log(_class);
```

or if you wish to alert is class then go with

```
alert(_class.attr('class'));
```

**EDIT 2**

If you wish `_class` to hold the class of the html item, the you should do

```
_class = $('.list').closest('*[class]').attr('class');
```

or

```
_class = $('.list').closest('*[class]')[0].className;
```

Comment: False, they want `console.log()` not `alert()`

Comment: I dont want the text or html, I need the "class" which is list1

Comment: @RUJordan: well, perhaps s/he really wanted that :) updated my answer anyway.

Comment: I would like to work with _class not just output in console. For instance this doesnt work: _class.replace(/ /g, '');

Comment: I'm glad it helped :) Feel free to upvote and/or accept the answer then!

Comment: @Matteo Tassinari I already upvoted and one can accept answer only after a period of time;)

Answer (score 1):

Because `$('.list').closest('*[class]');` is a jQuery object, `console.log(_class);` will reveal the object details.

**Edit** to get the class you would do something like `_class.attr('class')`

Answer (score 1):

Because what you're referencing to is an `object` it would always alert it that way.

If you need to get the text, you can use

```
alert(_class.text());
```

To get the class, use

```
alert(_class.attr('class')); // class attribute
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
var _class = $(".list").prevAll("[class]").first().attr("class");
alert (_class);
```

You shouldn't use `.closest()`, because that goes up the DOM hierarchy. You want to search the siblings before, that's what `.prevAll()` does, and then use `.first()` to get the nearest one.

Then to get the `class`, you use `.attr("class")`.

See this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/ApnLw/2/)